# How to write etl test cases in excel sheets

Tags: etl, informatica

I do not have an exact idea how to write ETL test cases.I did the following 3 scenarios.

```
1.source n target count should be same.
2.check duplicates in target
3.column mapping for source and target.
```

how will write test case for mapping.I am really confused.please help.please give me one sample test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test cases should include:

- Total record count for Source and Target should be same. (Total distinct count if any duplicates)
- Distinct Column count for all the common columns should be same.
- Total null count for source and target common columns should be same.
- Do source minus target and target minus source for common columns.
- If your mapping has aggregates then check sum of that column should match with target sum. Group it by month, year if you have any date column or key.
- If you mappings have lookups then left outer join that table with source and check if the same value is inserted.(You can add this column to distinct column count and minus queries)

Check what all transformations are there in mapping, see if the result matches with the source.

Answer (score 0):

The test cases are written on these following test scenarios:
**Mapping doc validation, structure validation, constraint validation, data consistency issues** etc.
Examples of some test cases are as follows:

1. Validate the source structure and target table structure against corresponding mapping doc.
2. Source data type and target data type should be same.
3. Length of data types in both source and target should be equal.
4. Verify that field data types and formats are specified.
5. Source data type length should not be less than the target data type & etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add

1. Validate post processing
2. Validate late arriving dimensions
3. Validate Data access layer against reports and target tables
4. Inserts, updates, deletes, null records test in source/stg tables/config tables etc.